# Paring the values of an array into a new key value paired array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ([order_variable_key] => surname [order_variable_value] => Hudsons )
    [1] => Array ( [order_variable_key] => number [order_variable_value] => 13 )
    [2] => Array ( [order_variable_key] => firstname [order_variable_value] => Dave )
)
```

I want to convert it to an array that looks like this:

```
Array(
    'surname' => Hudsons,
    'number' => 13,
    'firstname' => Dave);
```

I managed to isolate the values but was not able to pair them with eachother.
I want to pair the values of the nested array with eachother.

Comment: array_combine(array_column($array, 'order_variable_key'), array_column($array, 'order_variable_value'))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($array as $obj)
{
   $newArray[$obj['order_variable_key']] = $obj['order_variable_value']
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$new_array= array();
foreach($array_name1 as $key=>$val){
    $new_array[$val['order_variable_key']] = $val['order_variable_value'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$arr = // your array;

$data = array();
foreach($arr as $val)
{
    $arr[$val['order_variable_key']] = $val['order_variable_value'];
}

print_r($arr);
```

will give your desired format.

Comment: I finaly used the following solution:

Comment: I finaly used the following solution:

                $result = //my array here;
  $data = array();
  foreach($result as $val)
  {
      $data[$val['order_variable_key']] = $val['order_variable_value'];
  }
  
  print_r($data);